# Getting array data Json in Postgres

Tags: json, postgresql

I’m populating a Json field called output in the table runs with data from a process, just like this

```
{
"output": {
    "DATA": [
        [
            {
                "NumOrdem": "136726",
                "NumCliente": "4594731",
                "numConta": "440.10.600324-5",
                "numNota": "",
                "numCativo": "000001",
                "mensagem": "Mainframe - CL57 - Numero de referencia nao existe nas notas."
            }
        ],
        [
            {
                "NumOrdem": "136726",
                "NumCliente": "4594731",
                "numConta": "440.10.600324-5",
                "numNota": "",
                "numCativo": "000003",
                "mensagem": "Mainframe - CL57 - Numero de referencia nao coincide."
            }
        ]
    ]
}
```

}

And would like to extract this data, via Postgres, in a way to get something like this:

[image]

Is this doable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to unnest the array:

```
select data.jv ->> 'NumOrdem' as "NumOrdem",
       data.jv ->> 'NumCliente' as "NumCliente",
       data.jv ->> 'numConta' as "numConta", 
       data.jv ->> 'numNota' as "numNota",
       data.jv ->> 'numCativo' as "numCativo",
       data.jv ->> 'mensagem' as "mensagem"
from the_table t
  cross join jsonb_array_elements(t.output -> 'output' -> 'DATA') as a1(j1)
  cross join jsonb_array_elements(a1.j1) as data(jv)
```

`jsonb_array_elements` returns every element of the array as a JSON value, and the outer query simply picks the keys from that JSON value.

`as data(jv)` defines a [table alias](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-TABLE-ALIASES) together with a column name

If you are not using `jsonb` (why?) but `json`, then you need to use `json_array_elements()` instead.

Online example: https://rextester.com/XVYA32320

Comment: Doesn't work.... I'm not the DBA so I didn't choose the datatypes.... the result is null

Comment: @Fernando: ah! I didn't see that there are two layers of arrays. See my edit

Comment: Amazing! Thank you so much!